# Using SPLFixedArray in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, spl

I have a namespace declared as such:

```
namespace MySpace {

    $array = new SPLFixedArray();

}
```

Error I get is:

Fatal error: Class 'MySpace\SplFixedArray' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\private\config.php on line 25

Is there a namespace defined for all SPL functions, or am I doing something incorrect here? *scratches head*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use classes from the global namespace, prefix them with the namespace separator:

```
$array = new \SplFixedArray;
```

Or alias them like any other namespaced class:

```
use \SplFixedArray;
// ...
$array = new SplFixedArray;
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I was thinking it was a global namespace...why don't they just make these methods global without the namespace definer? Oi.

Comment: Because in namespaced code, everything has to have a namespace.  This lets you define your own class named `SplFixedArray` and stick it in `MySpace` without overriding (conflicting with) the global one.  You would just access it like `MySpace\SplFixedArray` instead of `\SplFixedArray`.